# How to check if wget is using proxy form a php page

Tags: php, proxy, wget

I'm using something like this:

```
$proxyip = array("199.201.122.219:443","202.120.88.12:8080","84.27.84.170:80");

$urlb = 'http://www.google.it/?q=';
$outputfile = "dl.html";
putenv('proxy=on');

for ($j=4 ; $j<8 ; $j++){
    $url = $urlb . urlencode($row[$j][0]);
    putenv('http-proxy="'.$proxyip[rand(0,2)].'"');
    $cmd = "wget -q \"$url\" -O $outputfile";
    exec($cmd);
}
```

And it all works great, but am I sure that wget is using a proxy?
Yes, if I look into the env, http-proxy is set.

Comment: I guess you could see if the proxy works if you go to say `http://whatsmyip.org` and print the output.

Comment: yep excellent idea thanks, now i'm sure that wget is not using it